# Append output from a loop to elements of a string vector in c++ Edited

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am working on linux server, but using g++ to run this c++ script. Fairly new to programming. I am trying to create a vector of strings `vector<string> Geno`  of genotypes. The file I am getting the data from looks like this:

```
chr38   12632   C  T  0/0:42,0:42:PASS:98   0/1:27,12:39:PASS:99  0/0:49,0:49:PASS:99
chr38   13825   G  T  0/1:37,13:50:PASS:99  0/1:28,9:37:PASS:99   0/0:46,0:46:PASS:99
chr38   17160   C  T  0/0:23,0:23:PASS:43   0/0:13,0:13:PASS:42   0/0:11,0:11:PASS:41
chr38   17451   G  A  0/0:22,0:22:PASS:61   0/1:13,12:25:PASS:99  0/0:9,0:9:PASS:28
chr38   19444   G  A  0/0:8,0:8:PASS:22     0/1:8,9:17:PASS:99    0/0:20,0:20:PASS:61
```

The columns are chromosome, position, then a ref and alt allele. The following 3 columns are dog genomes at those positions. I create a `Map.file`:

```
chr38 12632 C T
chr38 13825 G T
chr38 17160 C T
chr38 17451 G A
chr38 19444 G A
```

Which leaves the remaining file:

```
0/0:42,0:42:PASS:98   0/1:27,12:39:PASS:99  0/0:49,0:49:PASS:99
0/1:37,13:50:PASS:99  0/1:28,9:37:PASS:99   0/0:46,0:46:PASS:99
0/0:23,0:23:PASS:43   0/0:13,0:13:PASS:42   0/0:11,0:11:PASS:41
0/0:22,0:22:PASS:61   0/1:13,12:25:PASS:99  0/0:9,0:9:PASS:28
0/0:8,0:8:PASS:22     0/1:8,9:17:PASS:99    0/0:20,0:20:PASS:61
```

All of current code with Bob's first edits:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

  //function to get genotype for one SNP
  char con_hap2geno(const string & str)
  {

    char hap1 = str[0];
    char hap2 = str[2];

    if(hap1 =='0' && hap2 =='0')
        return '0' ;

    else
        if(hap1 == '0' & hap2 =='1')
          return '1';

        else
            if(hap1 =='1' & hap2 =='0')
              return '1';

            else
                if(hap1== '1' & hap2 == '1')
                  return '2';

                else
                    return '5';

  }//end of function

 struct raw_data{vector<string> s_geno;};//place to store dog columns
int main()
{
  fstream checkmarkermap; checkmarkermap.open("Mapfile", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc); checkmarkermap.close();
  string line;
  ifstream infile;
  infile.open("Chr38_3d_5snp.vfc");
  if(infile.fail()) {cout << "Error Opening File\n";}
  vector<raw_data>gen_file;

  while(getline(infile,line))
  {
     size_t pos = line.find("\t", 0);
     string Chrom  = line.substr(0,pos);
     line.erase(0, pos +1);

     pos = line.find("\t",0);
     string position = line.substr(0,pos);
     line.erase(0,pos+1);

     pos = line.find("\t",0);
     string REF = line.substr(0,pos);
     line.erase(0,pos+1);

     pos = line.find("\t",0);
     string ALT  = line.substr(0,pos);
     line.erase(0,pos+1);

     stringstream ssline{line};
     raw_data gData;
     string temp;
     while(ssline>>temp)
     {
     gData.s_geno.push_back(temp);
     }

      gen_file.push_back(gData);


    ofstream output2("Mapfile", std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out);//app appends, creates file
    output2 << Chrom << " " << position << " " << REF << " " << ALT << endl; //map file  
   }//end of getline while

int n_dogs= gen_file[0].s_geno.size();
         vector<string>f_genos(n_dogs);

        for (int i=0; i<n_dogs; ++i)
         {
                string genome;
         //"if need to reserve memory space". genome.reserve("size needed")
             for (auto & line_of_data; gen_file)
            {
             genome += con_hap2geno(line_of_data.s_geno[i]);
            }

            f_genos[i] = genome;
        }//end n_dogs file

        //create final genome file
        ofstream dogfile("Chr38_3d_5snp_genome");
        for (auto & i : f_genos){
        dogfile<<i<<'\n';       }

     return 0
 }
```

I got it to work up until (line 100) the second for statement after the `int n_dogs`. I get error `declaration of auto & line_of_file has no intializer.` I assume this is because `line_of_file` was not a declared variable, but unsure what to change it to.

I am trying to get to a file which looks like:

```
01000
11011
00000
```

which would correspond to each dog's genotype. I assume that I will have more problems once I get past that. Currently on same line I have error `could not convert gen_file to bool.` but I assume that has to do with the first error.

Comment: You cannot get this working without a better understanding of the basics of C++, and the best way to do that is to work up from simpler exercises. If you need working complex code soon, you should hire a coder.

Comment: Show the vfc file content

Comment: I suggest making an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and asking [specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: OK ill shrink it down.

Comment: @Ben please read the the posts in chat. You are mixing two different code snippets and keeping statements like `for ( auto ... : ... )` that are valid only in the new standard, but aren't supported by your compiler. Use the more recent code I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

Just a couple of thing about the code you posted.

If you know about `stringstream` and you used it for the last columns, why don't you used it for the entire line? I think that extracting data with code like this:

```
 size_t pos = line.find("\t", 0);
 string Chrom  = line.substr(0,pos);
 line.erase(0, pos +1);
```

is a useless complication when you could do it easier with `stringstrem`.

The way you're managing files isn't really clear. What's the purpose of this line?

```
 fstream checkmarkermap; checkmarkermap.open("Mapfile", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc); checkmarkermap.close();
```

You open and close that file without using it...

Then, when you write the data to MapFile you choose to open it (actually reopen without closing it), append new lines to the file at every iteration. I don't think it's a good idea nor very disk friendly. We are talking about relatively "small" files (up to ~30000 lines) and many IO operations with little chunk of data, it should be better to read the whole input file, store the data in some struct, elaborate it (in RAM) and then write the output files.

Please, read and try the following program and tell me if there's something wrong or that you don't understand.

**EDIT 1**

Thanks for clarifying. I rewrote my code and now should work as you expected.

I dropped all the c++11 features, so it should compile nicely with g++ 4.4.7.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::stringstream;

// use a function to extract the first and third char from a string and then return
// a char that represents some genetic information
char get_geno_char( const string &str ) {

    // to get the first and third chars in a string: 
    char hap1 = str[0];
    char hap2 = str[2];

    // chose the right value...
    if (hap1 =='0' && hap2 =='0')
        return '0';
    else if (hap1 == '0' && hap2 =='1')
        return '3';

    // to be completed...
    else 
        return '5';
}

// I'll use this class to store data read from a line of the input file
struct GenData {
    string chr;
    string pos;
    string ref;
    string alt;
    // here I will store the chars related to dogs genome
    vector<char> gen_dogs;
};

int main() {

    vector<GenData> geno_data;
    // If you are sure that there are ~30000 lines it may be better to reserve
    // enough space to avoid unnecessary vector expansions
    geno_data.reserve(40000);

    char fname_in[] = "Chr38_3d_5snp.vfc";

    std::ifstream infile(fname_in);
    if ( infile.fail() ) {
        cerr << "Error Opening File " << fname_in << '\n';
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Read all the lines in the file and store the values in a vector of 
    // structs. I don't know if your actual input file has headers for every
    // column like the snippet you showed earlier. In that case you can skip
    // the first line or simply read it to find out the number of dogs
    string line;
    while ( std::getline(infile,line) ) { 

        // skip empty lines if there are any
        if ( line.empty() ) continue;

        GenData gd_temp;

        // extract data from the line
        // I'm not sure if you actually need those data or you can skip
        // them to go the columns with dogs genome
        stringstream ssline(line);
        ssline >> gd_temp.chr >> gd_temp.pos >> gd_temp.ref >> gd_temp.alt;
        // the input file may be wrong formatted or unreadable
        if ( ssline.fail() ) break; 

        // extract dogs genome data from remaining columns
        string temp;
        while ( ssline >> temp ) {
            // Instead of storing an entire string read from the input file
            // like "0/0:42,0:42:PASS:98", we'll use the return value of  
            // get_geno_char() function to store the needed char
            gd_temp.gen_dogs.push_back(get_geno_char(temp));
        }
        // the number of dogs is geno_dogs.size(). To be extra paranoid you
        // can check if every line has the exact same amount of columns/dogs

        geno_data.push_back(gd_temp);
    }
    infile.close();

    // vectors (and strings) know their sizes... Please note that the actual
    // size() is different (smaller) from the space reserved
    size_t n_lines = geno_data.size();
    if ( !n_lines ) {
        // No line of data was read. Better to exit
        cerr << "Insufficient data.";
        exit(-1);
    }
    size_t n_dogs = geno_data[0].gen_dogs.size();

    cout << n_lines << " lines of data was succesfully read from file: " 
         << fname_in << "\nFound genome data of " << n_dogs << " dogs.\n";  

    // write Map.file
    char fname_map[] = "Map.file";
    std::ofstream mapfile(fname_map);
    if ( mapfile.fail() ) {
        cerr << "Error Opening File " << fname_map << '\n';
    }
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n_lines; ++i ) {
        mapfile << geno_data[i].chr << ' ' << geno_data[i].pos << ' '
                << geno_data[i].ref << ' ' << geno_data[i].alt << '\n';
    }
    mapfile.close();

    // Now write the dogs genome

    vector<string> dogs_genome;
    // We know exactly how big those strings will be, so let's size them
    // properly using resize(), not reserve() because we will not append
    // chars to the strings, but insert them in the right position
    dogs_genome.resize(n_dogs);
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n_dogs; ++i ) {
        dogs_genome[i].resize(n_lines);
    }

    // leaving the lines loop outside and the dogs loop inside may be
    // more cache friendly (faster), but I'm not really sure
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n_lines; ++i ) {

        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n_dogs; ++j ) {

            // geno_data[i] stores line i of data read
            // gen_dogs[j] is the char needed in the i position of  
            // dog genome string j
            dogs_genome[j][i] = geno_data[i].gen_dogs[j];
        }
    }

    // write file Dogs.dat

    char fname_dogs[] = "Dogs.dat";
    std::ofstream dogfile(fname_dogs);
    if ( mapfile.fail() ) {
        cerr << "Error Opening File " << fname_dogs << '\n';
    }

    // you added an ID in the previous version of the question
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n_dogs; ++i ) {
        // this will add an ID like D01 (you may have more then 9 dogs)
        dogfile << 'D' << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << ( i + 1 )
                << ' ' << dogs_genome[i] << '\n';  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running that code I got two output files, the first, "Map.file" contains:

```
chr38 12632 C T
chr38 13825 G T
chr38 17160 C T
chr38 17451 G A
chr38 19444 G A
```

The second, "Dogs.dat" is (hopefully) what you need:

```
D01 03000
D02 33033
D03 00000
```

Comment: I made it more clear and edited it slightly. I get an error when i try to use to_string event though i have using namespace std and include <vector> <string>

Comment: @Ben please, see the update. Are you compiling using a c++11 compliant compiler?

Comment: I have scanned your code but I am stuck working with a 4.4.7 version g++ sadly. I will let know know when I run it if that causes issues, even with the option. My main file I can create with or without the headers. I  will have probably ~90 dogs and ~30 mil Pos across the 39 total chr.

Comment: @Ben That shouldn't be a big deal. Later I'll change the braced-initiailizers and the range-for loops in my code to the old standard equivalents. Is the output what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the help. i think i am going to try to incorporate this more than just rewriting so that i better understand it. The output (assuming it works for me) is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @Ben I fixed the code, now it should compile without any problem. If this is what you were looking for, please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;).

Comment: Is there a way to chat instead of a list of comments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103237/discussion-between-ben-and-bob).